# Invalid Column Using Row_Number()

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am attempting to only select the 1st row returned from the query.  This is my syntax ->

```
insert into @Temp (id, salesID)
select
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by t.psUserID)
    ,t.psUserID
from (
    select distinct 
    psUserID = rstln.Bama   
    From rusticlines rstln  
    AND tnr.Active = '1') t
WHERE RN = 1;
```

And I get the error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 51
>   Invalid column name 'RN'.

What do I need to change so that it only selects the 1st row number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [Logical Processing Order of the SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql). Anything can reference an item further up the list than itself but nothing at its own level or below.

RN doesn't exist yet in your query. You can use a derived table or a CTE to fix the error.

```
insert into @Temp (id, salesID)
select RN, psUserID
from (
select
    RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order by t.psUserID)
    ,t.psUserID
from (
    select distinct 
    psUserID = rstln.Bama   
    From rusticlines rstln       -- more syntax issues 
    AND tnr.Active = '1'         -- here
     ) t) d
WHERE RN = 1;
```

Answer (score 10):

With your example in the question, you could skip the whole `ROW_NUMBER()` thing and just use `TOP (1)`:

```
INSERT INTO @Temp (id, salesID)
SELECT TOP (1) 1, Bama
FROM rusticlines AS rstln  
WHERE Active = '1'
ORDER BY Bama;
```

For more complex queries (where you need to get first row in a partition), you could probably make something useful with [`TOP (1) WITH TIES`](https://sqlsunday.com/2013/09/01/using-top-n-with-ties/).